# jQuery datepicker not working no error message

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Our new website:

http://www.serviced-lettings.co.uk/central-london/canary-wharf-apartments-2/?theme=new-serviced

I have tried to initialize the jquery date picker on an input field class name dateinput also tried by the ID no luck no script warnings showing in my firebug.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.dateinput').datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd" );
    });
    </script>
```

i am loading in the ui and jquery through wordpress.

Am i missing something? been on this 2 days now

Comment: does it work if you try just **.datepicker()** without options?

Comment: Based off documentation shouldnt it be **.datepicker({
  dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
});**

Comment: I have also trued the suggestions but geting this error: uncaught exception: Missing instance data for this datepicker

Comment: actually it works now i am seeing that error in firefox only with firebug enabled, it looks like firequery is casuing an issue on firefox https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebug/lNuGov5VTqo/NxN-b2oTqB0J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$( ".dateinput" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
});
```

[image]

Comment: Aha I was a little slow.

Comment: Was geting this error: uncaught exception: Missing instance data for this datepicker, now it works, after disabling firequery, it looks like firequery is casuing an issue on firefox groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebug/lNuGov5VTqo/NxN-b2oTqB0J

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing the datepicker incorrectly.  Take a look at [the documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat).

```
$( ".dateinput" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
});
```

Also, be sure you are including JQuery and JQuery UI *before* this script.